# Low-Flow Nozzles for Corrosion Spray Testing

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, applied-mechanics, hydraulics

So, for a cyclic corrosion test system, I need a nozzle or arrangement of nozzles that provides a flow rate of 45ml-140ml of salt solution per hour to an area 60cm square. All commercial nozzles I've been able to find with non-flat spray patterns have much higher flow volumes. Does anyone know if a specialty supplier for this type of equipment?

Also, I need to ensure that the area is saturated as evenly as possible - what sort of FEA or simulation program would be best for analyzing the distribution of mass/fluid in a spray arrangement?

Comment: If you want droplets, you'll need a fluidics based distributor like a windshield washer nozzle that operates for a few seconds every minute. Otherwise you can use a mister in a fan box. I think four windshield nozzles in a big box would do pretty well. You may need to swap out the nozzles and clean them pretty often though.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a standard salt spray cabinet ? I am sure it can use different salts other than sea salt. Those we had were roughly 4 ft. cubes which may be big for your work , but may have future uses. And a standard unit results are easy to compare to literature and/or publish.  And as a standard unit it would have some resale value. I don't remember the particular manufacturer but it was some years ago and they have probably changed names.

Comment: The project is to design and construct the test apparatus, so that's not really a viable option.

Comment: Designing it to conform to a standard remains a good design choice, however.

Comment: That is the plan - but I'm not sure what kind of apparatus the desktop-size modules use for the spraying. At this point, I'm thinking we'll need to either look into cannibalizing replacement parts for a COTS unit or destining from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Look into *mister* sprinkler heads for *drip irrigation* systems. Big hardware stores sell a wide variety of these. They are cheap and easy to work with using the sprinkler supply tubing and fitments that are offered for sale with them. Some of these have low flow designs (measured in gallons per hour). Note that you'll need a good filtration cartridge in the flow because the mister nozzles can be easily plugged by dirt or corrosion products. A cheap disposable plastic fuel filter for use on a car or motorcycle will work fine for this and can be bought in an auto supply store.

the perfect pump would probably be a 12-volt DC one scabbed from the windshield washer pump setup in a car. These can be bought at car junkyards for cheap.